# Why can I run this azure resource group deployment script outside of visual studio?

Tags: azure, powershell, deployment, visual-studio-2017, azure-resource-manager

Using Visual Studio 2017,

- I created a new Azure Resource Group Deployment project from template.
- I replaced the content of the parameters and template file with ones I had already generated from another resource group that I had manually created.
- I right clicked on the project and deployed.
- I discovered that the resources deployed to another subscription of mine that was not selected in the drop-down menu.
- While trying to discover how it was selecting the target subscription, I copied the generated powershell deployment script, parameters and template file to another folder *that did not have the visual studio project in it*.
- I ran the powershell script, and the resources deployed as before *without requiring any credentials of mine*.

I believe that visual studio has stored my credentials and deployment settings somewhere, but I can't discover where. I suspect it's some fixed location that's known by powershell because the script works from any directory on my system, but I haven't been able to discover any information about where that might be.

**How am I able to run this script from anywhere, and where is the magic file that has my creds in it (if it exists)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to clear powershell's Azure Resource Manager Context, which it had cached.

```
Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope CurrentUser
```

(Thanks to [HariHaran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8368871/hariharan) for pointing me in the right direction.)

Answer (score 1):

If you start a Powershell somewhere and try running `get-azureAccount` or `Get-AzureRmAccount` if it returns results of your Azure credentials then it indicates PowerShell contains your account login in the cache.

Run this to remove the cached credentials.

```
 Get-AzureAccount | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureAccount $_.ID -Force }
```

After running the command, all of your cached credentials will be removed and your system will be clean. Cheers! I have done the same thing previously when my pc went rogue with someone else's credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, `Get-AzureAccount` does not return anything. I even tried signing out of visual studio, thinking that powershell was looking for a visual studio credential cache or something, and that still didn't work.

Comment: Can you try `Get-AzureRmAccount`